# A question about higher K-theory

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{A,B,C}$ are additive categories, $\mathcal B$ is a subcategory of $\mathcal C$. Now let $F,G: \mathcal A\rightarrow\mathcal B$ be two additive functors. Suppose $F,G$ are naturally equivalent as functors  $\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal C$, do they induce the same map $K_n(\mathcal A)\rightarrow K_n(\mathcal B)$? Of course, $\mathcal{A,B,C}$ are endowed with the split exact structures.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes if the natural isomorphisms $F(X)\cong G(X)$ are in $\mathcal B$.

Comment: Thanks Fernando, that's right if the natural isomorphisms are in $\mathcal B$ by applying the additivity theorem. I don't know whether it is still true if the isomorphisms are in the ambient category $\mathcal C$. I guess probably it's not true.